# Session is empty when request from messenger

Tags: python, session, heroku, facebook-messenger

I have developed chatbot for messenger and deployed in heroku. When user writes(messenger sends post request) i try to set session, but after request, session is empty. With postman i have tested and everything works perfect. I want to know what is the reason? 
Here is how i set session:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session

@app.route('/set', methods=['POST'])
def set():
    session["language"] = "en"
    print(session) //<SecureCookieSession {'language': 'en'}>
    return "added", 200
@app.route('/get', methods=['POST'])
def get():
    print(session) //in messenger <SecureCookieSession {}> in postman <SecureCookieSession {'language': 'en'}>
    return "get"
```

Comment: Flask stores the session info all in its cookie.

Comment: @aristotll ok and? how should i save session then?